# Predicate protected-prolog error

Tags: prolog

```
option(d):-write('Delete existing route'),nl.
   write('Please key in the type of transportation[c=byCar/p=byPlane/t=byTrain] '),read(R1),nl,
   write('Please key in the starting point of destination: '),read(S1),nl,
   write('Please key in the ending point of destination: '),read(D1),run4(R1,S1,D1),nl,
   write('Delete existing travelling alternative record success!'),nl,nl,menu.
```

It shows predicate protected. May i know how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you have a period after `nl` on the first line instead of a comma, so it looks to Prolog like you're redefining the comma operator instead of defining an `option/1` predicate. But that's just where your problems start.